# Perform PCA on each group of a groupBy in PySpark

Tags: python, machine-learning, pyspark, pca, apache-spark-mllib

I am looking for a way to run the `spark.ml.feature.PCA` function over grouped data returned from a `groupBy()` call on a dataframe. But I'm not sure if this is possible, or how to achieve it. This is a basic example that hopefully illustrates what I want to do:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
from pyspark.ml.feature import PCA   

df = spark.createDataFrame([[3, 1, 1], [4, 2, 1], [5, 2, 1], [3, 3, 2], [6, 2, 2], [4, 4, 2]], ["Value1", "Value2",  "ID"])

df.show()
+------+------+---+
|Value1|Value2| ID|
+------+------+---+
|     3|     1|  1|
|     4|     2|  1|
|     5|     2|  1|
|     3|     3|  2|
|     6|     2|  2|
|     4|     4|  2|
+------+------+---+

assembler = VectorAssembler(inputCols=["Value1", "Value2"], outputCol="features")

df2 = assembler.transform(df)

df2.show()
+------+------+---+---------+
|Value1|Value2| ID| features|
+------+------+---+---------+
|     3|     1|  1|[3.0,1.0]|
|     4|     2|  1|[4.0,2.0]|
|     5|     2|  1|[5.0,2.0]|
|     3|     3|  2|[3.0,3.0]|
|     6|     2|  2|[6.0,2.0]|
|     4|     4|  2|[4.0,4.0]|
+------+------+---+---------+

pca = PCA(k=1, inputCol="features", outputCol="component")
```

At this point I have the dataframe and the pca object that I want to use. I would like to now perform PCA on the dataframe but grouped by "ID", so I would get the PCA for all of the features with ID 1, and the PCA for all of the features where ID is 2, just returning the components. I can get these manually by:

```
>>>> pca.fit(df2.where("ID==1")).pc
DenseMatrix(2, 1, [-0.8817, -0.4719], 0)
>>>> pca.fit(dff.where("ID==2")).pc
DenseMatrix(2, 1, [-0.8817, 0.4719], 0)
```

But I would like to run this over all of the different IDs in the dataframe in parallel, something like:

```
df2.groupBy("ID").map(lambda group: pca.fit(group).pc)
```

But you can't use `map()` on grouped data like this. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: I need to do something similar. I'm considering writing a UDAF that computes a covariance matrix from the grouped vectors, using the code from Spark's RowMatrix class as a guide, then calling Breeze's SVD on the covariance matrix to produce the PCA matrix.

Comment: Did it work in the end?

Comment: Why won't you wrapped what you did manually in a `for loop` over each unique ID ? You could then `union` the resulting dataframe back into one. To my knowledge, this will also be run in parallel.

Comment: And you would have control over the aggregation process since PCA does not aggregate  .

Answer (score 1):

### Spark>=3.0.0

As of `Spark 3.0.0`, you can use [`applyInPandas`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.GroupedData.applyInPandas.html) to apply a simple Python function to each group of the current DataFrame and return the result as another DataFrame. You basically need to define the output schema of the returned DataFrame.

Here I will use **scikit-learn**'s [`PCA`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) function instead of the Spark implementation as it has to be applied to single pandas DataFrames, not Spark ones. The principal components to be found should be the same anyway.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, DoubleType


# define PCA parameters
cols = ['Value1', 'Value2']
pca_components = 1


# define Python function
def pca_udf(pdf):
    X = pdf[cols]
    pca = PCA(n_components=pca_components)
    PC = pca.fit_transform(X)
    PC_df = pd.DataFrame(PC, columns=['PC_' + str(i+1) for i in range(pca_components)])
    result = pd.concat([pdf, PC_df], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
    return result


# define output schema; principal components are generated dynamically based on `pca_components`
to_append = [StructField('PC_' + str(i+1), DoubleType(), True) for i in range(pca_components)]
output_schema = StructType(df.schema.fields + to_append)


df\
  .groupby('ID')\
  .applyInPandas(pca_udf, output_schema)\
  .show()

+------+------+---+-------------------+
|Value1|Value2| ID|               PC_1|
+------+------+---+-------------------+
|     3|     1|  1| 1.1962465491226262|
|     4|     2|  1|-0.1572859751773413|
|     5|     2|  1|-1.0389605739452852|
|     3|     3|  2|-1.1755661316905914|
|     6|     2|  2|  1.941315590145264|
|     4|     4|  2|-0.7657494584546719|
+------+------+---+-------------------+
```

---

### Spark<3.0.0

Before `Spark 3.0.0` - but still with `Spark>=2.3.0` - the solution is similar but we need to actually define a [`pandas_udf`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.pandas_udf.html), a vectorized user-defined function executed by Spark using Arrow to transfer data and Pandas to work with the data. The concepts to define it are similar to the previous ones anyway.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField, StructType, DoubleType
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType


# macro-function that includes the pandas_udf and allows to pass it some parameters
def pca_by_group(df, cols, pca_components=1):
    # build output schema for the Pandas UDF
    # principal components are generated dynamically based on `pca_components`
    to_append = [StructField('PC_' + str(i+1), DoubleType(), True) for i in range(pca_components)]
    output_schema = StructType(df.schema.fields + to_append)

    # Pandas UDF for applying PCA within each group
    @pandas_udf(output_schema, functionType=PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
    def pca_udf(pdf):
        X = pdf[cols]
        pca = PCA(n_components=pca_components)
        PC = pca.fit_transform(X)
        PC_df = pd.DataFrame(PC, columns=['PC_' + str(i+1) for i in range(pca_components)])
        result = pd.concat([pdf, PC_df], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
        return result
    
    # apply the Pandas UDF
    df = df\
        .groupby('ID')\
        .apply(pca_udf)
    
    return df


new_df = pca_by_group(df, cols=['Value1', 'Value2'], pca_components=1)
new_df.show()

+------+------+---+-------------------+
|Value1|Value2| ID|               PC_1|
+------+------+---+-------------------+
|     3|     1|  1| 1.1962465491226262|
|     4|     2|  1|-0.1572859751773413|
|     5|     2|  1|-1.0389605739452852|
|     3|     3|  2|-1.1755661316905914|
|     6|     2|  2|  1.941315590145264|
|     4|     4|  2|-0.7657494584546719|
+------+------+---+-------------------+
```